# Learn Python the Hard Way Example 15

Tags: python

In example 15 of Learn Python the Hard Way. Why is script one of the arguments or variable for argv?

```
    from sys import argv
    script, filename = argv

    txt = open(filename)

    print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
    print txt.read()

    print "Type the filename again:"
    file_again = raw_input("> ")

    txt_again = open(file_again)

    print txt_again.read()
```

I'm just confused since file_name is the only thing that is being asked for from the terminal.

Comment: I believe (don't quote me) script is the name of the file of your script. If you run `python myscript.py myfile`, `script` should hold `myscript.py`, and `filename` should hold `myfile`

Comment: The first argv entry is the scripts name. This is consistent with the way C does it.

Comment: argv always holds running script name in index 0 thus `script, filename = ["scriptname.py", "yourfile.txt"]`

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html),

sys.argv is

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `sys.argv` is the script name/path and it is passed automatically.

For example,

```
 $ script.py filename.txt
```

`argv` gives `["script.py", "filename.txt"]`

Answer (score 0):

> Why is script one of the arguments or variable for argv?

Here the authors are assuming that `argv` is an array of length 2 (It is always an array, but in this case a specific length).

A more clearer example:

```
x, y = [5, 4]
print x  # 5
print y  # 4
```

In the case of `argv` it will give you the name of your script as well as the argument you passed in (`my_scripy.py --arg0 val0`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I found for this exercise it is best to have a text file called ex15_sample.txt in the same root folder, this way when you put through `python ex15.py ex15_sample.txt`it would pass the script name to *script* and would open the filename **ex15_sample.txt**

 hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Script is automatically an argv argument. That is true because everything after you type python3.6 or python(depending on the system you work on) is counted as an argv. This is stored in a list like this:

```
argv = [ex15.py, ex15_sample.txt]
```